# Moving files from S3 bucket from a range of dates using Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, lambda

In my S3 bucket I have two folders, I would like to make one of them an archive while the other keep only a week old data, I thought of making a scheduled Lambda function (node js)

Any thoughts on how I can do that?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can I suggest an alternate option to move files for archival without nodejs?

Comment: Thank you Pronoy999 after playing with the life cycle rule in S3 i found our that my files are very small and the S3 life cycle doesnt support small files
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a scheduled `NodeJS Lambda`, you can setup `AWS S3 bucket lifecycle policy` to do that exact task in a much easier way.

**You can also move files to various classes of `S3` for cheaper storage costs.**

Use this [AWS Docs link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html) to follow the steps and you will be able to set it up easily.

Comment: After playing with the life cycle rule in S3 I found our that my files are very small and the S3 life cycle doesnt support small files 
Any other ideas?